# Custom ImageView button not working in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am using v7 `Toolbar` for `ActionBar`. I am using a `ToggleButton` in Toolbar with images. I cannot capture any click events on `Toolbar` neither `ToggleButton`nor Navigation Drawer button.

Here is my code (OnCreate method):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tv_on= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_on);
    toggleButton= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    // displayView(0);
    tv_on.setText("OFF");
    checked=false;
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    FragmentOff off = new FragmentOff();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, off, "HELLO");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checked == false) {
                tv_on.setText("ON");
                android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentOff off = new FragmentOff();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, off, "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                checked = true;
            } else {
                tv_on.setText("ON");
                android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentOn on = new FragmentOn();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, on, "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#D92027"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/work_status"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_work" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/off"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_on"
        android:text="@string/off"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

home_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.webninjaz.fragment.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong. Even I can't debug onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

You can put image and button inside toolbar you need to use AppBar layout

http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/

Please refer this link.Hope its works.

Comment: link tells how to use menu items but mine can't be used as menu item

Comment: You need to put image inside CollapsingToolbarLayout bot in toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

please change from

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
tv_on= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_on);
toggleButton= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.toggle);
```

to

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
tv_on= (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_on);
toggleButton= (ImageView)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
```

Comment: Still no luck . When I am debugging debugger skips whole onClickListener method

Comment: try attaching listener before setting toolbar to actionbar

Comment: on which line you have applied debugging..also click event is still not captured?

Comment: @VivekMishra you can apply logs inside the onClick and then check whether logs are printed or not and if yes which statements are printed. If you attached listener on onClick and during debug mode then initially it will skip when listener is attached to the view; I mean its inner code won't be executed.

Comment: Logs are not printed either. I can see touch dispatch events in log when click on button but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help but I re-implemented my navigation drawer and toolbar and now everything is working fine.This was probably a bug with navigation drawer template provided by Android Studio